# Connect ZKTECO device from hosted django Site gives an error

Tags: python, django, zkteco

I have created a site that connect ZKTECO K40 device. The connection Method is pretty simple:

```
from zk import ZK, const
zk = ZK('192.168.1.13', port=4370, timeout=5)
conn = zk.connect()
```

This makes a connection while running from a local host connecting in the same network.

But after hosting the site, the site is not able to ping to the device and cannot connect to the device.

How can I connect to the device connected on pc local network from a hosted django site? I have my site hosted on Cpanel.

[image: ZKNetworkError at /handle/pullData can't reach device (ping 192.168.1.13) Request Method: GWT]

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to expose your local IP first. step 1 would be to contact your ISP and ask them if you have a static/real IP address. step 2, go to your router settings and use NAT to port forward or just expose it so that you can ping it from anywhere. from here, you will be able to do your thing. additionally, check Step 3, check your server's outbound rules.

Answer (score 0):

From the server, a machine which is connected to some local network can not be connected.  You have to use cams biometric api for communicating your biometric device from the remotely hosted application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.zerotier.com/ - to expose the device over the internet and then connect it. It's not advisable. but thats one way.